# Summarize line lengths in raster cells in ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap

I calculated lines from buildings to streets and want to summarize these lengths in regular raster cells.
Any idea how to calulate the sum of lines in raster cells?
Maybe splitting up each line at a converted polygon (regular raster to polygon) -> intersect -> calculate lengths of each segment -> spatial join of sum from lines -> convert back to raster.

Is there a more simple way to do that?

[image]

Comment: [Line density tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/line-density.htm)?

Comment: unfortunately i do not need any density without any search radius etc..
I just need the sum of the length of lines within a raster cell.

Comment: Then yes your outlined approach would be the way to do it.

Comment: had some problems with splitting the lines at raster edges, but solved it somehow with a search radius in the size of a raster cell. Lathough it splitted also segments where there are no points, but the small segments get summed up anyway!
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it with summarize lengths within converted raster cells to polygons. By spatial join and the rule "within polygons" I could summarize the lengths.
Before I had to split the lines by polygon borders I created with a fishnet.